# Как создать файл сразу в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Мне хотелось бы сразу создавать файлы и открывать их в ST3, а то приходится создавать файл и только потом через ST открывать его, это неудобно и долго.
Я у одного ютубера видел такую вещь, что когда он создаёт файл вот так:
[image: фыв]
в указанном стрелкой окне был раздел "текстовый файл Sublime Text 3" или чуть по-другому, кто-нибудь знает, как это сделать?

Comment: К чему такие сложности? Нажимайте Ctrl+N в ST, затем сохраняйте этот новый файл (Ctrl+S).

Comment: @eanmos когда файл уже есть и его нужно открыть, нужно сначала открыть ST, потом открыть этом файл через ST,  каждый раз это очень долго проделывать, а с помощью той функции, файлы, когда их открываешь, открываются сразу в ST, также и если их создавать, они создаются как  "текстовый файл Sublime Text 3" и всегда в ST открываются

Comment: Если файл уже есть, его можно открыть в ST с помощью Ctrl+O. Хотя лучшим вариантом было бы воспользоваться т. н. Side Bar.

Comment: https://g-ek.com/kak-redaktirovat-dobavlyat-udalyat-elementyi-iz-kontekstnogo-menyu-v-windows-10

Comment: `%sendto%` - обычно (на win10) `C:\Users\ИмяПользователя\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`